# Navigation Timing API domInteractive fired before responseEnd (dom interactive fired before response end)

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, w3c, msdn, navigation-timing-api

According to the Navigation Timing API documentation, DOM Interactive is triggered when the whole document is parsed. ResponseEnd is triggered when the last byte of the response is received. Looking at our real world data (visitors to my site) I saw numerous cases where the DOM Interactive events happens before the Response End event, mainly in Internet Explorer 9+. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the spec says 'This attribute must return the time immediately before the user agent sets the current document readiness to "interactive".' It can be interactive before it is all loaded. However, I will say that in my data, MSIE sets this property well before the others. The others seem to set it at or near domContentLoadedEventStart. Perhaps that is a better metric to use rather than domInteractive.

Comment: The W3C's [test suite](http://w3c-test.org/web-platform-tests/master/navigation-timing/test_timing_attributes_order.html) says that `domInteractive` should not come before `responseEnd`.